# ReactJS: IE 10 Compatibility, Set is undefined

Tags: reactjs, polyfills, babel-polyfill

I am trying to get ReactJs compatible with IE 10 and have added the following import statements before any other import.

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

The import is done in the index file of my app, App.tsx.

However I am still getting the following error and am unable to resolve it.

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Set' is undefined
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also run in this same issue. To solve this, you need some additional node packages in order to perform polyfills. 
Please, 1st install the npm package "**core-js**". After that, add

```
import 'core-js/es/set'
import 'core-js/es/map'
```

If still running into issues, install this other package **react-app-polyfill** and add the following additional import:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9'
```

These **imports** must be in the root **index** file of your project. Hope this helps.

Comment: this indeed helped. the full import I had to do: import 'console-polyfill';
import '@babel/polyfill';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/date';

Comment: import 'core-js/es/set'
import 'core-js/es/map'
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9'
after importing.. it didn't work.

Comment: You need to inspect the console log and be sure the error is coming from your extension. Do u have the error details?